# How can I run a shell command in Windows without the shell closing itself automatically?

Tags: windows-7, wubi

[According to this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99112/wubis-root-disk-is-missing-but-you-can-still-log-in-as-a-guest-where-is-the/99118#99118), I run that command but a black page flashes and disappears. What should I do to see the result?

I rebooted but it doesn't take effect.

Comment: Also, I hope you do realize that all of the commands from the mentioned post are supposed to be run on Linux?

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs I assumed the user is referring to `chkdsk` as this self-closing-shell seemed more of a "Windows problem" to me.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg You must be right. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
- Type `cmd` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Type your command in the resulting window, it should stay open after the command has finished.

To run a command with elevated privileges (as Administrator), do the following (Vista/7 only):

- Press <kbd>Win</kbd>
- Type `cmd` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, confirm the following dialog by pressing "Yes".
- Type your command in the resulting window, it should stay open after the command has finished.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It says "access denied as you do not have sufficient privileges, you have to invoke this utility running in elevated mode". Could you please tell  me what "elevated mode" is?

Comment: @Gigili I added additional instructions to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of running

```
ping example.com
```

you can do

```
cmd /k ping example.com
```

and the cmd window will remain open. Generally i use "cmd /k " to run something and keep it open until i close it